# Why does the Twitter API give me a code 32 (could not authencate) error?

Tags: curl, twitter, twitter-oauth, libcurl

I'm trying to make a search request to the twitter REST api.
Here is my request:

> GET /1.1/users/search.json?q=%23PLLFinale HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api.twitter.com
>   User-Agent: PostPirate v1.0
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="(removed)", oauth_nonce="Ts3s7nlxSN6lfK9eqJOoujc8U3FmywOU", oauth_signature="(partially-removed)lmMzY4YzgwY2JhMzFlYTc4ZDEwNTMyYWM1MGU1MmYxMQ%3D%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1498607144", oauth_token="(removed)", oauth_version="1.0"

and here is the parameter string for my signature:

> oauth_consumer_key=(removed)&oauth_nonce=Ts3s7nlxSN6lfK9eqJOoujc8U3FmywOU&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1498607144&oauth_token=(removed)&oauth_version=1.0&q=%23PLLFinale

and here is the signing key:

> (removed)&(removed)

and here is the signature base string:

> GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fusers%2Fsearch.json&oauth_consumer_key%3D(removed)%26oauth_nonce%3DTs3s7nlxSN6lfK9eqJOoujc8U3FmywOU%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1498617068%26oauth_token%3D(removed)%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26q%3D%2523PLLFinale

Here is the response I'm receiving back:

> {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was calculating the signature wrong. I did not realize that the result of my HMAC-SHA1 calculation were a series of hexadecimal bytes. I treated them as a string and passed them directly into my base64 conversion function.
I also recommend using this to check your signature base string:
http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `count` parameter was exceeding the **max allowed count number** of **100**, which was changed recently by Twitter API. So, the new right API call URL should be in my case:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=100
```

But the most annoying thing was that I was getting

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

Instead of logical "limit param exceeded" like with Facebook API.

This is only one of the cases where you will get this **misleading error** and end up with something totally different.